# iOS CoreBluetooth Receive Data

Tags: ios, swift2, core-bluetooth

I'm working on a project where I communicate with a micro controller over BLE. I can successfully send Data with the following Code:

```
func writeValue(data: String){
    let data = (data as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if let peripheralDevice = peripheralDevice{
        if let deviceCharacteristics = deviceCharacteristics{
            peripheralDevice.writeValue(data!, forCharacteristic: deviceCharacteristics, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't find anything about how to receive data. I want to display received Data in a UILabel. Anyone know how to set up a function which is called when there is data sent to the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to write then reading data is much more easy .
First you need to scanner the service from which you want to receive data. like

```
peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
```

When a service is found following delegate method will be called .Then you need to Discover Characteristics from which you want to read data

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
    self.statusLabel.text = "Looking at peripheral services"
    for service in peripheral.services {
        let thisService = service as CBService
        if service.UUID == yourseviceid {
            // Discover characteristics of  Service
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: thisService)
        }
        // Uncomment to print list of UUIDs
        //println(thisService.UUID)
    }
}
```

When central Discover Characteristics for the given service the didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService method of CBPeripheralDelegate protocol gets called

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {



    // check the uuid of each characteristic to find config and data characteristics of the one you are interested 
    for charateristic in service.characteristics {
        let thisCharacteristic = charateristic as CBCharacteristic
        // check for data characteristic
        if thisCharacteristic.UUID == yourcharUUID {
            // Enable Notification to if the if it will be updated periodically and you want to update 
            peripheralDevice.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic)
//Or just read the value if you just want to read
peripheralDevice.readValueForCharacteristic(thisCharacteristic)
        }

    }

}
```

then your value will be revived in following delegate method.

```
// Get data values when they are updated
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {



    if characteristic.UUID == yourUUID {
        // Convert the revived NSData to array of signed 16 bit values
        let dataBytes = characteristic.value

        //parse the data received and display where you want 



    }
}
```

Comment: On my micro controller I will send back the data it got from the iPhone but when I want to display values I get from the micro controller I just get "Optional((00))" from characteristic.value

Comment: How you get and parse the value? can you post the code please?